# winston - not able to log the console message to file

Tags: node.js, winston

I want to log all of the messages from Console using Winston,
and use `winston-daily-rotate-file` to daily store and remove the logs.

In Console:

```
{"level":"info","message":"Feathers application started on localhost","timestamp":"5/26/2021, 10:44:36 AM"}
You will see this message every 60 second
You will see this message every 60 second
You will see this message every 60 second
```

When I view the log file `application-2021-05-26.log`,

```
{"level":"info","message":"Feathers application started on localhost","timestamp":"5/26/2021, 10:44:36 AM"}
```

`You will see this message every 60 second` is missing in the log file.
What's wrong here?

app.js

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
const moment = require('moment');

new CronJob('10 * * * * *', function() {
  console.log('You will see this message every 60 second');
}, null, true, 'Asia/Singapore');
```

logger.js

```
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
const winston = require('winston');
require('winston-daily-rotate-file');

const timezoned = () => {
  return new Date().toLocaleString('en-SG', {
      timeZone: 'Asia/Singapore'
  });
}

const logger = createLogger({
  level: 'debug',
  format: format.combine(
    format.splat(),
    format.simple(),
    format.json()
  ),
  transports: [
    new transports.Console(),
    new winston.transports.DailyRotateFile({
      filename: 'application-%DATE%.log',
      dirname: "logs",
      datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
      zippedArchive: true,
      maxSize: '20m',
      maxFiles: '2d',
      format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.timestamp({ format: timezoned }),
        winston.format.json(),
      ),
    })
  ],
});

module.exports = logger;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `logger.log` function inside your `CronJob` definition.

Please check out this [Minimum Viable Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-mtxqrr?file=index.js) to see how you should configure your codebase to see the logs both on your console and on your file.

When you run the example (using `node index.js`), the script will emit logs to the console and a local file inside the project's root.

Here is the entire script for reference:

```js
const { CronJob } = require('cron');
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
const moment = require('moment');
require('winston-daily-rotate-file');

const timezoned = () =>
  new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-SG', {
    timeZone: 'Asia/Singapore'
  });

const logger = createLogger({
  level: 'debug',
  format: format.combine(format.splat(), format.simple(), format.json()),
  transports: [
    new transports.Console(),
    new transports.DailyRotateFile({
      filename: 'application-%DATE%.log',
      dirname: '.',
      datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
      zippedArchive: true,
      maxSize: '20m',
      maxFiles: '2d',
      format: format.combine(
        format.timestamp({ format: timezoned }),
        format.json()
      )
    })
  ]
});

const job = new CronJob(
  '10 * * * * *',
  () => logger.debug("You'll see this message every 60 seconds"),
  null,
  null,
  'Asia/Singapore'
);

job.start();
```